# Is Require.JS the right tool for the job?

Tags: javascript, object, module, requirejs

Ok I am relatively new to JavaScript, probably really about 4-5 months-ish of dabbling. However I want to improve my JavaScript to match the way I code in general.

I am usually a PHP developer, and use Composer to load in my classes to work with. Does Require.JS allow me to do this? For example, a quick snippet of what I would call a **module** is :

```
var tabs = function(paramOps) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.opts = {
        header: {
            target: 'tabbedHeader'
        },
        content: [{
            id: '',
            title: 'Default Title',
            descr: 'Data is yummy'
        }]
    }
    $.extend(true, _this.opts, paramOpts);
    _this.render = function() {
        // YOU GET THE IDEA
    }
    return _this;
}
```

I would then load in my module using :

```
var tabs = new tabs();
tabs.render(paramOpts); // paramOpts is defined elsewhere
```

Ok so without having a beast of an application JS file, am I able to load these in as Modules using Require.JS?

Comment: Sorry! I am just used to formatting my Markup! With edit now

Comment: `var tabs = new tabs();` is a really tricky example, you probably wanted `var t = new tabs();` or something (e.g., not the same name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok so without having a beast of an application JS file, am I able to load these in as Modules using Require.JS?

Yes. Suppose you define that in `tabs.js`. Then you'd do:

```
var Tabs = require("./tabs.js");
```

(I'm not a require expert, so I don't know why that needs the leading `./`, but [it's shown in this example linked from the Require website](https://github.com/volojs/create-template), so...)

But it can go a *lot* further than that. For instance, you can use `define` in your `tabs.js` to give it a name that gets resolved rather than a filename, e.g.:

`tabs.js`:

```
define("tabs", function() {
    // ...create your Tabs function

    return Tabs;
});
```

Then to use it:

```
var Tabs = require("tabs");
```

Or if you're using it in another component elsewhere in your app, maybe `ui.js`, and you want to use `define` in `ui.js`, then:

`ui.js`:

```
define("ui", ["tabs"], function(Tabs) {
    // Use Tabs here

    // Return whatever it is the 'ui' module defines
});
```

That sets up a dependency: RequireJS knows that loading `ui` must involve loading `tabs`, and so does it and then provides `ui` with its dependencies as arguments to the `define` callback.

---

Side note: Best to stick to conventions, if you're going to call a function as a constructor (e.g., via `new`), it should be initially-capped: `Tabs`, not `tabs`.

Comment: Thanks! I would usually do this with PHP however out of inexperience with OOP JavaScript I wasn't sure on the best approach/methods

Comment: Ok so with your example, am I then able to access Tabs.render() like I did previously?? Is this the best way for me to do it?

Comment: @JustSteveKing: The `Tabs` you get from `require` is a reference to the object you return from `define`, I've added more examples.

Comment: @JustSteveKing: No worries. I'm not a Require expert, so do kick around the docs and examples. Some of the above may need a call to `requirejs.config` to set up.